# showing time in negative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Issue: I have successfully calculated TotalTime a person has worked and overtime he has done if total working time is greater than 08:00 but if not greater than it puts 00:00 in Overtime for that employee BUT NOW I DON'T WANT THIS, I WANT THAT IF PERSON HAS WORKED LESS THAN 8 hours than overtime column should display that time in negative e.g. if person has worked 7:00 hours than Overtime column should show -1 (in proper hours format)

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else '00:00' end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Comment: In this case no need of Case statement, you can directly used convert(char(6),cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time), 108) as overtime

Comment: please edit my code sir to show it, i'm receiving errors

Comment: You'll have to do a lot of it as manual string formatting. SQL Server's `time` datatype is intended to hold a time of day, not a time interval. As such, it's only set up to hold values >= `00:00` and < `24:00`. It can't store anything outside this range.

Answer (score 0):

Then the last part of your query would look like this:

```
SELECT EmplID
  ,EmplName
  ,InTime
  ,[TimeOut]
  ,[DateVisited]
  ,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
  ,convert(char(6), 
     CASE WHEN TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:00' 
          THEN convert(char(5),cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time)) 
          ELSE '-' + convert(char(5),'08:00' - CAST(TimeOutSub-InTimeSub AS time)) 
     END
   ,108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Comment: Please take a look at the revised query

Comment: error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Changed to char(6) and converted the positive overtime

Comment: now it shows negative sign with value but values are wrong, e.g. -23:29

Comment: or -18:01 for a person whose total time is 05:59

Comment: actually it shows that second value correctly after : but first is false, e.g. -23:29 should be -00:29 , -18:01 should be -00:01

Comment: Changed to '08:00' now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45880/discussion-between-nickyvv-and-evil-rising)

Answer (score 0):

Overtime Calculation

```
 case when cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time) <  CAST('08:00' AS TIME) then '-' + convert(char(5), cast(dateadd(hour, 0, '08:00' ) - ([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub) as time), 108) ELSE convert(char(5), (TimeOutSub- InTimeSub )   - cast(dateadd(hour, 0, '08:00' ) as time), 108)   end as overtime
```

Last Query

```
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,case when cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time) <  CAST('08:00' AS TIME) then '-' + convert(char(5), cast(dateadd(hour, 0, '08:00' ) - ([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub) as time), 108) ELSE convert(char(5), (TimeOutSub- InTimeSub )   - cast(dateadd(hour, 0, '08:00' ) as time), 108)  end as overtime
FROM times
```

Code changed . try it.

Comment: Code changed. Please try it

Comment: he data types datetime and time are incompatible in the less than operator.

Comment: amazing, but still one problem, it doesn't show (-) minus sign with value

Comment: Intime : 14:49 OutTime : 15:20 Overtime : 07:29

it should be -07:29

Comment: Put minus infront of it.  '-' + convert(char(5), cast(dateadd(hour, 0, '08:00' ) - (LastOutTime - FirstInTime) as time) , 108)

Comment: wait wait wait. i have figured something wrong in it, it shows time if person has not completed 8 hours, that's ok but now it doesn't show if person overtime for those who have worked 8 hours +

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else cast(8 - (TimeOutSub - InTimeSub) as time) end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Comment: sir, ERROR: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'totaltime'.

Comment: sir it gives wrong output: 
for timeIn 14:49 and timeOut 15:20 it gives OVERTIME=23:29 while totaltime = 00"31

Comment: sorry sir i don't know about that

Comment: actually it shows that second value correctly after : but first is false, e.g. -23:29 should be -00:29 , -18:01 should be -00:01

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Try This, I just changed the condition of case TimeOutSub - InTimeSub <> '08:00'
-- and character length to 6 for negative value, All the Best!!!
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
    , t3.EmplName
    , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
    , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
    , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
    , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
    , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
  AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
  HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
      t1.EmplID
    , t3.EmplName
    , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(6), 
case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub <> '08:00' then cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8,     InTimeSub) as time)          
     else '00:00' end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Answer (score 0):

Again i would say use function to calculate Work Hrs & Over Time, I shared that in your last Question, using that you can easily manage & change as per your requirement, try this script (in e.g 8 hrs =480 min)

```
    CREATE FUNCTION GetWorkHours(@INTime AS DateTime, @OutTime AS DateTime,@WorkingHrsINMinutes AS INT)
    RETURNS @WorkHours TABLE
    (
         WorkHours   Varchar(6),  
         OTHours     Varchar(6)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @WorkHours
    SELECT CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime)) / 60 AS VARCHAR(2))+ ':' 
           + CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime)) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS TotalTime,
           CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime)  > @WorkingHrsINMinutes 
                THEN CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime) -@WorkingHrsINMinutes) / 60 AS VARCHAR(2))+ ':' +
                     CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime) -@WorkingHrsINMinutes) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)) 
           WHEN DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime)  < @WorkingHrsINMinutes 
                THEN '-' +
                     CAST((DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime) -@WorkingHrsINMinutes) / 60 AS VARCHAR(2))+ ':' +
                     CAST((ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, @INTime, @OutTime) -@WorkingHrsINMinutes)) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))           
           ELSE '00:00'
           END AS OverTime

    RETURN
    END
    GO

    SELECT * From Dbo.GetWorkHours('2014-01-22 10:00:09.270','2014-01-22 18:10:09.270','480')
    SELECT * From Dbo.GetWorkHours('2014-01-22 10:00:09.270','2014-01-22 17:10:09.270','480')
```